# Scifi Story about an obsolete robot which we find out is a human?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading this story as a child where a family is getting ready for an event in the centre of the city, where the last robot is being turned off, since it became obsolete.
At the end of the story we find out the whole population is made of robots and the robot being killed is an old human.
I remember reading it in an italian anthology school book, the author wasn't Italian though.

Edit:
I read it around 2010 I think, I am pretty sure the story was older though.
I do remember that the family was made up of a father a mother and a little girl, which microowaved a toy, don't know if that information would be useful...

Comment: Hi, off to a good start, but we could probably use some more details, such as when you read it or when you think it was published, for a start. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help you add in some more details.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into your question. Answers belong in answers. I have reverted your edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the OP's edit above, this is "L'ultimo robot" by [Lorenzo Beccati](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenzo_Beccati). It can be found in his collection *La notte dei commercialisti viventi* published March 1994.

Interestingly, ISFDB is not aware of this author, nor the collection, nor the story. However, the Italian language website fantascienza.com has a [list of the collection's contents](http://www.fantascienza.com/catalogo/volumi/NILF123371/la-notte-dei-commercialisti-viventi/).

Comment: ISFDB is a database into which people can contribute. If you'd like, I can do that based on that site.